# How to count rows from a different table based on same date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

**EDIT** although the accepted answer doesn't match what I was looking for at the moment I wrote this question, it does show a better way of what I had already (which is what they want) the data in the production tables are what is wrong, meaning that the numbers are wrong.

I'm struggling to create the sql statment to create the report at the bottom of this post. I've included the statments to create my tables and test data. So to get started here is the Creation statement for the picture_stats

```
CREATE TABLE [picture_stats](
    [PICTURE_STATS_ID] [int] NULL,
    [USER_NAME] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [DATE_TIME] [datetime] NULL,
    [SIZE] [float] NULL,
    [CLICK_COUNT] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Insert statement that puts data into picture_stats

```
INSERT INTO [picture_stats]
           ([PICTURE_STATS_ID]
           ,[USER_NAME]
           ,[DATE_TIME]
           ,[SIZE]
           ,[CLICK_COUNT])
VALUES
    (1 ,'A','2015-05-18'75,18),
    (2 ,'A','2015-05-18'13,18),
    (3 ,'A','2015-05-18'42,16),
    (4 ,'A','2015-05-18'59,16),
    (5 ,'A','2015-05-18'46,14),
    (6 ,'A','2015-05-18'64,16),
    (7 ,'A','2015-05-18'87,13),
    (8 ,'A','2015-05-18'84,14),
    (9 ,'A','2015-05-18'33,16),
    (10,'A','2015-05-18'59,14),
    (11,'B','2015-05-19'10,17),
    (12,'B','2015-05-19'44,18),
    (13,'B','2015-05-19'29,14),
    (14,'B','2015-05-19'65,19),
    (15,'B','2015-05-19'10,15),
    (16,'B','2015-05-19'55,18),
    (17,'B','2015-05-19'81,11),
    (18,'B','2015-05-19'29,11),
    (19,'B','2015-05-19'58,19),
    (20,'B','2015-05-19'20,17),
    (21,'C','2015-05-20'35,16),
    (22,'C','2015-05-20'70,18),
    (23,'C','2015-05-20'30,13),
    (24,'C','2015-05-20'33,13),
    (25,'C','2015-05-20'43,19),
    (26,'C','2015-05-20'10,15),
    (27,'C','2015-05-20'33,13),
    (28,'C','2015-05-20'23,12),
    (29,'C','2015-05-20'35,18),
    (30,'C','2015-05-20'58,19)
GO
```

Table view of the data.

```
ID USER_NAME DATE_TIME  SIZE CLICK_COUNT
-- --------- ---------- ---- -----------
1  A         2015-05-18 75   18
2  A         2015-05-18 1    18
3  A         2015-05-18 42   16
4  A         2015-05-18 59   16
5  A         2015-05-18 46   14
6  A         2015-05-18 64   16
7  A         2015-05-18 87   13
8  A         2015-05-18 84   14
9  A         2015-05-18 33   16
10 A         2015-05-18 59   14
11 B         2015-05-19 10   17
12 B         2015-05-19 44   18
13 B         2015-05-19 29   14
14 B         2015-05-19 65   19
15 B         2015-05-19 100  15
16 B         2015-05-19 55   18
17 B         2015-05-19 81   11
18 B         2015-05-19 29   11
19 B         2015-05-19 58   19
20 B         2015-05-19 20   17
21 C         2015-05-20 35   16
22 C         2015-05-20 7    18
23 C         2015-05-20 30   13
24 C         2015-05-20 33   13
25 C         2015-05-20 4    19
26 C         2015-05-20 100  15
27 C         2015-05-20 33   13
28 C         2015-05-20 23   12
29 C         2015-05-20 35   18
30 C         2015-05-20 58   19
```

The second table picture_comment_stats can be created with this:

```
CREATE TABLE [picture_comment_stats](
    [PICTURE_STATS_ID] [int] NULL,
    [USER_NAME] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [DATE_TIME] [datetime] NULL,
    [CLICK_COUNT] [int] NULL,
    [LIKES] [int] NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

To script in the data:

```
INSERT INTO [picture_comment_stats]
    ([PICTURE_STATS_ID]
    ,[USER_NAME]
    ,[DATE_TIME]
    ,[CLICK_COUNT]
    ,[LIKES])
VALUES
    (1 ,'X','2015-05-18',75,18),
    (2 ,'X','2015-05-18',1 ,18),
    (3 ,'X','2015-05-18',42,16),
    (4 ,'X','2015-05-18',59,16),
    (9 ,'X','2015-05-19',34,16),
    (10,'X','2015-05-19',57,14),
    (11,'Y','2015-05-19',11,17),
    (12,'Y','2015-05-19',44,18),
    (17,'Y','2015-05-20',81,11),
    (18,'Y','2015-05-20',29,11),
    (19,'Y','2015-05-20',55,19),
    (21,'Z','2015-05-20',45,16),
    (20,'Y','2015-05-21',20,17),
    (22,'Z','2015-05-21',7 ,18),
    (23,'Z','2015-05-21',30,13),
    (24,'Z','2015-05-21',39,13),
    (25,'Z','2015-05-21',4 ,19),
    (26,'Z','2015-05-21',10,15),
    (27,'Z','2015-05-21',33,13),
    (28,'Z','2015-05-21',23,12),
    (29,'Z','2015-05-21',35,18),
    (30,'Z','2015-05-21',58,19)
GO
```

The table should look like this.

```
ID USER_NAME DATE_TIME  COMMENT_ID LIKES
-- --------- ---------- ---------- -----
1  X         2015-05-18 75         18   
2  X         2015-05-18 1          18   
3  X         2015-05-18 42         16   
4  X         2015-05-18 59         16   
9  X         2015-05-19 34         16   
10 X         2015-05-19 57         14   
11 Y         2015-05-19 11         17   
12 Y         2015-05-19 44         18   
17 Y         2015-05-20 81         11   
18 Y         2015-05-20 29         11   
19 Y         2015-05-20 55         19   
21 Z         2015-05-20 45         16   
20 Y         2015-05-21 20         17   
22 Z         2015-05-21 7          18   
23 Z         2015-05-21 30         13   
24 Z         2015-05-21 39         13   
25 Z         2015-05-21 4          19   
26 Z         2015-05-21 10         15   
27 Z         2015-05-21 33         13   
28 Z         2015-05-21 23         12   
29 Z         2015-05-21 35         18   
30 Z         2015-05-21 58         19
```

What I want to do is make a report of the data such that I have the user name, the count of the pictures, and the count of comments on an individuals picture. The picture_stats_id in both tables is actually a foreign key which points to the table 'pictures' primary key picture_id. The report I want to be able to choose a date or a date range and have it show like so: I'm hoping the report would show the following for the different 3 day scenarios

```
(Filtered for Date:2015-05-18)
USER_NAME PICS COMMENTS
--------- ---- --------
A         10   4

(Filtered for Date:2015-05-19)
USER_NAME PICS COMMENTS
--------- ---- --------
B         10   2

(Filtered for Date:2015-05-20)
USER_NAME PICS COMMENTS
--------- ---- --------
C         10   1

(Filtered for Date:2015-05-18 to 2015-05-19)
USER_NAME PICS COMMENTS
--------- ---- --------
A         10   6
B         10   2

(Filtered for Date:2015-05-19 to 2015-05-20)
USER_NAME PICS COMMENTS
--------- ---- --------
B         10   2
C         10   1

(Filtered for Date:2015-05-18 to 2015-05-20)
USER_NAME PICS COMMENTS
--------- ---- --------
A         10   6
B         10   5
C         10   1
```

so far all I have is

```
SELECT ps.USER_NAME as USER_NAME,
    COUNT(*) as PICTURE_COUNT,
    SUM(1) AS COMMENT_COUNT -- can't figure out this statement for nothing.
from picture_comment_stats pcs
RIGHT OUTER JOIN picture_stats ps ON ps.PICTURE_STATS_ID = pcs.PICTURE_STATS_ID
--WHERE ps.DATE_TIME BETWEEN @beginFilterDate AND @endFilterDate
GROUP BY ps.USER_NAME
ORDER BY ps.USER_NAME
```

**EDIT**

The fiddle address as was given in the below comments: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/74e77

To clarify the counts I'm try to get. The second column, would be the number of pictures said user posted that day. the third column is how many comments were made on a users picture for that specified day ONLY. So even though X commented on A's picture a total of 6 times (on the 18th, and 19th) I only want to count 4 if I filter for the 18th, and 6 if i filter on the 18th-19th. It's a little hard to follow I'm sure, but that's what is wanted.

Comment: can you please post a sql fiddle for this?

Comment: What is the logic behind `PICS` and `COMMENTS` columns?

Comment: @DeepakPawar That's the part I don't know. I'm just trying to count how many comments are attached to a picture on a given day(s)

Comment: @vkp This is a cool sight.. but it won't let me build my first table, says my syntax is wrong, but I used SSMS to build the majority of the script

Comment: There are some open brackets and commas missing in script.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with all the data in it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8315d, actually seems like I'm missing a table though, the query you wrote uses other tables than the ones you provided

Comment: Why are your tables named picture_stats and picture_comment_stats, but those tables aren't used in your posted query attempt?   Anyway, I would approach this with a select from picture_stats to get picture count, and a correlated subselect from comment_stats to get the comment count.

Comment: @TabAlleman mistake on my part, i copied the wrong query in. I'll fix it in a second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT --ps.USER_NAME as USER_NAME,
    s.user_name,
    count(distinct c.comment_id) as comments,
    count(s.picture_stats_id) as pics
    --COUNT(*) as PICTURE_COUNT,
    --SUM(1) AS COMMENT_COUNT
    from --commenting.transcription_audit_stats pcs
   -- RIGHT OUTER JOIN commenting.transcription_stats ps ON ps.SURVEY_STATS_ID --= pcs.SURVEY_STATS_ID 
    picture_stats s
    left join picture_comment_stats c
    on s.picture_stats_id = c.picture_stats_id
    and s.date_time = c.date_time
    where s.date_time between --specified date range
    --WHERE ps.DATE_TIME BETWEEN @beginFilterDate AND @endFilterDate    
    --GROUP BY ps.USER_NAME
    --ORDER BY ps.USER_NAME
    group by s.user_name,s.date_time
```

Try this and get the user name from the lookup table you have. Also filter on the dates you need.

Comment: Although close, I am hoping to not found comments made on a users picture if the comment was made outside the filtered date range. I've updated my question hopefully to reflect better what i'm looking for.

Comment: I added the where clause on my end when I was going through the values. If you make it `where s.date_time = '2015-05-18'` and compare your results with what I'm hoping to get up in my post you'll see the difference

Comment: what's needed finally? :)

Comment: Basically someone said.. Hey look at these numbers they are wrong! and pointed out a few things, instead of saying "Hey there are some things missing from the report" as in not all the stats of those things were added to the table (meaning the query is right as it currently is)